# Programatically select first item in a UWP TreeView

Tags: uwp, treeview

How can I programmatically select a TreeViewItem within a UWP treeview? Specifically I would like to select the first item in my tree.

I'm using data binding. I know I can bind on the `IsSelected` property, however, the object I'm binding against doesn't have such a property and would like to avoid writing a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the TreView's style, you could find that in its ControlTemplate, it actually uses a [TreeViewList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeviewlist#definition) control.

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewStyle1" TargetType="TreeView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanDragItems" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="CanReorderItems" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <ContentThemeTransition/>
                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                    <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl" AllowDrop="{TemplateBinding AllowDrop}" CanReorderItems="{TemplateBinding CanReorderItems}" CanDragItems="{TemplateBinding CanDragItems}" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyleSelector}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerTransitions="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerTransitions}" ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The TreeViewList class inherits from `ListView`. The ListView has SelectedItem property.

So, you could make a custom TreeView control which inherits TreeView class. Then, you could find the TreeViewList control by calling its `GetTemplateChild()` method. After that, you could set the selectedItem for it.

Please check my code sample:

```
public class MyTreeView:TreeView
{
    TreeViewList treeViewList;
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        this.Loaded += MyTreeView_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyTreeView_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeViewList != null)
        {
            treeViewList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        treeViewList = this.GetTemplateChild("ListControl") as TreeViewList;
    }
}
```

But with this way, you could only set the selectedItem for the RootNodes. If you want to selecte the sub node, I still think the binding on the `IsSelected` property is the better way.

Comment: Thanks Xavier for the explanation. It looks like SelectedNode will be coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedNodes` Property can be `set` too.
Which means, this should work:

```
myTreeView.SelectedNodes = new List<TreeViewNode>{ myTreeView.RootNodes[0] };
```

Comment: In principle this looks fine, however SelectedNodes is read only calling `.Add` on it doesn't work

Comment: @Sam The TreeView control is not like the a regular list view control has selectedItem property. It enables a hierarchical list and contain nested items. It maybe has N-level nesting. Currently, I think that binding on the IsSelected property is a not bad choice in practice.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I worked around this for now by using `x:Bind local:Class.ShouldSelect(property)`. There is discussion on WinUI at Github about adding a SelectedNode property which should ultimately fix this for now.

Comment: Comment, setting IsSelected in the TreeViewItem will select the node but will not fire the Invoked event.